# Cassandra With Java All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

I'm getting started with Cassandra, I can connect with "cmd", I have Java, python installed. (My keyspace name is Alvaro, my tablename is alumnos)
Well I have this issue

---

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (null))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:196)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1104)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:121)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:198)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:226)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:9)
```

---

My program is pretty simple I just want to connect and insert

'

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
    public class Test2{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Session session ;
                // Connect to the cluster and keyspace "alvaro"
                Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build(); 
                session=cluster.connect("alvaro");
                //Inserting into alumnos 
                session.execute("INSERT INTO alumnos (matricula, nombre, edad) VALUES (now(),'Alvaroxx',23)");
            }
    }
```

If I run the app with only the lines 1-8 it doesn't break.
But I can't connect, I've been trying all the week Installing a lot of jars
btw my jars are.

C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\cassandra-driver-core-2.0.2.jar
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\guava-16.0.1.jar
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\metrics-core-3.0.2.jar
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\netty-3.9.0.Final.jar
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\lz4-1.3.0.jar
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\snappy-java-1.1.7.2.jar
 
C:\apache-cassandra-3.0.18-bin\cassandra_jars\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

Please, help me Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver cant connect to 127.0.0.1:9042
So that means that you either have a firewall blocking 9042 on localhost or your server is not running correctly.

Have you tried connecting with a 3rd party tool, like the cassandra nosql manager? https://www.mongodbmanager.com/cassandra

What are the logs from the server saying? Verify that the server is listening on the correct interface.